# Will apps < IOS6.1 work on IOS7

Tags: ios7

I have just installed IOS7 Beta 6 on my ipad 2. No problems. 
Then with Xcode 4.6(with IOS6.1 SDK), I installed the current version of my app on my device with IOS7 and it runs and works perfectly. Now, from what I can gather the UDID or [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier] should no longer be available on IOS7. My app won't even compile with XCode5 because of it so does anyone know why my app designed for IOS6.1, using IOS6.1 SDK still runs on IOS7. Is there some provisioning in IOS7 for this?.
When Apple say that [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier will be no longer available, do they just mean apps will be rejected if they use it but apps submitted before the release of IOS7 will still work?

Any help much appreciated

josh

Comment: We can not discuss matters relating to iOS 7 because it is still under NDA, please post any iOS 7 or XCode 5 related questions onto the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Yes your application will be be rejected if you use UDID in your application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old apps still work in iOS7, however (!) UDID returned by uniqueIdentifier will be different. So if your application depends on that you would need to accommodate that change.

Answer (score 2):

Apps submitted before the release will still work as they are using the old iOS6 SDK.

To build the app with the new SDK you need to remove references to UDID and use an app specific identifer like the advertising identifier

Answer (score 1):

(no trade secrets here)

Maybe they just check that you're not using it when you submit to the app store?

Surely there must be lots of hidden stuff which is technically available, but they don't want you using.